# Twisted web - redirects in request

Tags: python, twisted.web

I was wondering if it is possible to redirect from within a render method in twisted web.

I have tried the various ways of redirecting and have only found it documented when used in the getChild method.

Basically I am checking to see if a user is logged in and if it isn't then forward the user onto a different Resource.

```
    def render_GET(self, request):
        player = getPlayer(request)
        if player.loggedIn():
            return Redirect("play")
        else:
            return Redirect("login")
```

I have looked all over but I am unable to find a well documented example on twisted documents.

I am not sure if I need to change my approach to this and I am new to twisted web. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apologies

Upon further investigation and by fault of my own I had overlooked the "`redirectTo`" method of twisted.web.util

This has worked for me perfectly for me. Just thought I would post this here in case anyone else is looking for the same answer.

```
    from twisted.web.util import redirectTo

    def render_GET(self, request):
        player = getPlayer(request)
        if player.loggedIn():
            return redirectTo("play")
        else:
            return redirectTo("login")
```

Kind regards
Joe

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I wonder if the method has changed between Twisted versions, or if your code never worked? The [current code](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/web/util.py) expects you to pass a `Request` in the call to `redirectTo`, so you could do `return redirectTo("play", request)`

Comment: @RoundTower thanks for your post. I'm no longer using Twisted but this code did work for me at the time. They may have changed something in the API.

Comment: This no longer works, use `from twisted.web.util import Redirect; return Redirect(url)`, which is a subclass of `Resource`, `redirectTo` returns a string, which is missing a `render` method. `Redirect.render` returns `redirectTo` for you. (twisted version 14.0)

Comment: @RoundTower - just for posterity the new code location for redirectTo is here: https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/web/util.py#L40

Comment: In case somebody stumbles across this. In python3 it should now be `return redirectTo(b"play", request)`. It expects a byte string.